# How to filter data on many to many fields and apply ANY and OR operators in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 3 Models defined in my code Day, AllocationType and EmployeeAllocation. I am trying to solve a problem for following scenarios.

**Scenario 1:**
If person A is allocated to project P1 from 01-06-2023 to 30-06-2023 for dyas M,T,W,T,F. If end user try to allocate person A in that date period or days then end user should get a validation error.

> *Person A is allocated.*

**Scenario 2**
If person B is allocated to project P2 from 01-06-2023 to 30-06-2023 for days M,W,F. If end user try to allocated person B than end user should able to allocated Person B between 01-06-2023 and 30-06-2023 for days T,T.

I am novice in Django and not able to figure out how to write a condition for checking above scenarios.

**Model Definitions**

```
class Day(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class AllocationType(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    ColorCode = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
class EmployeeAllocation(models.Model):
    Employee= models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=False, on_delete= MY_PROTECT, related_name='employee_allocation')
    Project= models.ForeignKey(Project, null=False, on_delete=MY_PROTECT, related_name='employe_allocation_project')
    AllocationType = models.ForeignKey(AllocationType, null=False, on_delete=MY_PROTECT, related_name="employee_allocation_type")
    StartDate = models.DateField()
    EndDate = models.DateField()
    Days = models.ManyToManyField(Day, null=False, blank=False, related_name='emoloyee_allocation_day')
    Comments = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('employee-allocation-list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Employee.FirstName
```